# Dissolution of Tensors

Tags: linear-logic

I have a question that might seem odd to linear logic experts (I am somewhat of a novice). I know that two items of the same type can be combined into one premise with a tensor (multiplicative conjunction). Is the opposite also possible? Say, that we have a premise $A\otimes B$, but the only other premise needs the premises $A$ and $B$ to be inserted individually.
Is this at all possible? Or is there some rule against this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It’s not quite clear to me what the question is, but anyway, a sequent $\Gamma,A,B\Longrightarrow\Delta$ is interderivable with $\Gamma,A\otimes B\Longrightarrow\Delta$.

Comment: May I suggest that some linear logician (not me, notwithstanding [this book](http://paultaylor.eu/stable/Proofs+Types)) give an explanation of $\otimes$ for the general enlightenment of MO readers. This requires that the question *not* be closed. I am not aware that Stefan Kohl and Alex Degtyarev are experts in this subject.

Comment: When I voted to close this, it looked to me as a very vague question in terribly broken English... I've retracted my vote.

Comment: I know linear logic quite well but unfortunately I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "opposite"?  Are you asking about reversibility of the tensor rule?  (If that's the case, the answer is no, the tensor rule is irreversible).

Comment: @DamianoMazza Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted to know. Sadly not what I had hoped, but still, thank you. I have opened another question, of which I hoped you might be so kind as to respond to: [http://mathoverflow.net/q/201157/69644](Link)

Comment: Zerkezhi, I suggest you focus on Emil's comment instead. The answer I gave to your other question suggests that his interpretation is the relevant one. I think what Damiano is saying is that $A \otimes B \vdash A, B$ is not valid in linear logic, and that's true, but that's because a list of formulas to the right of the entailment symbol is to be interpreted as a linear disjunction, not conjunction. But I suspect that observation is not relevant here.

Comment: @Todd actually I meant irreversibility in the proof-theoretic sense: given a proof of $\Gamma\vdash A\otimes B$, if you know that the last rule introduces $A\otimes B$, then you know there are proofs of $\Gamma_1\vdash A$ and $\Gamma_2\vdash B$ with $\Gamma_1+\Gamma_2=\Gamma$ but in general you still don't know how to determine $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$.  This is unrelated to the derivability of $A\otimes B\vdash A,B$ (the so-called "mix" rule), but I think it is still not what Zerkezhi was asking :-)

Comment: @DamianoMazza Okay, thanks for clarifying. I think what Zerkezhi was asking was essentially answered at the other thread, and is related more to what Emil wrote. But of course the question above was ambiguous, and your interpretation was a reasonable one.